# React blank page loads if I add a "/" at the end of my url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-4

I have this issue where my Webpack can't render the bundle created if I type a `/` at the end of my url.

For example - this loads fine `http://localhost:3000/sign-up` but this throws a white page `http://localhost:3000/sign-up/`.

I don't have a publicPath set for my Webpack bundle, but if I do set the publicPath to `'/'` then it fixed the `/` issue at the end of the url but it stops any of my images from loading and the file path of the images results in being `//assets/img/image.png` rather than a single slash.

Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my Webpack config:

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.js',
  devtool: 'inline-source-map',
  output: {
    // publicPath: '/',
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    filename: 'index.bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    port: 3000,
    watchContentBase: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    proxy: {
      "/api": "http://localhost:6000",
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
        exclude: /nodeModules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      use: [
        'style-loader',
        {
          loader: 'css-loader',
          options: {
            modules: {
              auto: true,
              // localIdentName: "[local]--[hash:base64:5]",
            },
          },
        },
        {
          loader: 'sass-loader',
          options: {
            implementation: require("sass")
          }
        },
        {
          loader: 'postcss-loader',
          options: {
            postcssOptions: {
              plugins: [
                  "postcss-preset-env",
                  "postcss-100vh-fix"
              ],
            },
          },
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
      loader: 'file-loader',
      options: {
        name: '/assets/img/[name].[ext]',
      }
    },
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: './src/index.html',
      favicon: "./assets/img/developer-filip-favicon.png"
    })
  ],
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out so I will answer my own question for anyone having similar problems.

The publicPath set to `'/'` was the way to go.
To fix the images not loading, the name of the path has to start with `./assets` and not just `/assets`.

Thanks for any help anyway!